# add arguments to callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code:

```
function addn (pathname, callback) {
    fs.readFile(pathname, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(pathname, data.replace(/>/g, '>\n'), function() {
            callback ();
        });
    });
};
```

But when I call it

```
addn('path/to/file', anotherfunction(whichhavecallback(){});
```

I get this error:

```
callback();
             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /path/to/my/js.js:610:13
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

It worked when I was calling simple function like console.log, why does it won t now?

Comment: As you wrote a syntactically invalid code in your question it's somewhat hard to figure what was the real code and thus your problem.

Comment: The code you've provided is going to error with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` before it even tries to call the callback.

Comment: You need to provide a (minimal) example of `anotherfunction` (so we can see what it returns) and a replacement for your call to `addn` that won't error by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a callback function in, you omit the `()`, else that function will execute immediately and be pointless, so try:

```
addn('path/to/file', anotherfunction);
```

And in your code

```
callback (); //-< insert parameter here!
```

Comment: Dumb me, that was that, and I had almost all the rest of my code like that